# than (it) seems/appears

Tags: ellipsis, comparative, linking-verbs, dummy-pronouns

**(1a)** *These boxes contain more toys than **it seems** possible*. — as far as I know, it's correct
**(1b)** *These boxes contain more toys than **seems** possible*. — is it correct?

**(2a)** *These boxes contain more toys than **it appears** possible*. — as far as I know, it's correct
**(2b)** *These boxes contain more toys than **appears** possible*. — is it correct?

**(3a)** *These boxes contain more toys than **it seems** at first sight*. — as far as I know, it's correct
**(3b)** *These boxes contain more toys than **seems** at first sight*. — is it correct?

**(4a)** *These boxes contain more toys than **it appears** at first sight*. — as far as I know, it's correct
**(4b)** *These boxes contain more toys than **appears** at first sight*. — is it correct?

As far as I know, all variants with "*it*" are correct. But I am interested to know which of them remain correct and which do not, if we remove "*it*"?
After this, could you explain to me please, based on these examples, when we can say "*than it appears/seems*" without "*it*" and when we must say it only with "*it*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3b and 4b are incorrect. The rest are correct.

It's a complex story, with reasons within reasons. Let's start.

There's no difference here between "seems" and "appears", so I'm just going to talk about "seems" to keep things simpler.

The reason lies in the different structures of "*[seems possible]*" and "*[seems] [at first sight]*".

I've separated the phrase "at first sight" because it's not connected to "seems". That phrase could be at the beginning of the sentence, or not there at all, and it wouldn't change the grammar. It is not the same function as "possible", which is a *subject complement* in the verb phrase "seems possible".

So, we're left with the two verb phrases, "seems possible" and "seems".

The "it" is optional with the phrase "than _____ seems possible", but required in "than _____ seems".

The reason "than it seems" is acceptable without a subject complement is that we understand an elided "than it seems (it is/there were/we are/...)".

The expression "... than seems" has either no subject or no subject complement, so it makes no sense.

Comment: _These boxes contain more toys than seems they can_. - is it correct without "_it_"? Thanks. (by your logic, since "_they can_" is connected to "_seems_", therefore, "_than seems they can_" is as correct as "_than seems possible_")

Comment: @Loviii No, that sentence is not correct, and I'm sorry, but I don't know what the significant difference is between "seems possible" and "seems they can". It might be the difference between *[ "seems" + adjective ]* and *[ "seems" + clause ]*, but I really don't know. This is truly one of the hardest questions I've answered in the last year. I wish I could upvote it more ;)

Answer (score 1):

1,and 2 **with** "it" sound awkward to me and not really idiomatic.

3 and 4 **without** it sound awkward to me and not really idiomatic.

than <s>it</s> seems **adjective/adjectival phrase, etc**.

than **it** seems **adverb/adverbial phrase, etc**.